# How to add a superscript or a subscript to an axis label to a 3D plot in plotly?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

How to add a superscript or a subscript to an axis label to a 3D plot in plotly?

I tried  to use `bquote`, but it did not work. Googling did not bring much on the matter either.

Scavenged code:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(123)

n <- 100
theta <- runif(n, 0, 2*pi)
u <- runif(n, -1, 1)


base<-'B1'
compare<-'A1'
plot (1, 1, main = bquote('Annual mean' ~CO[2] ~'Flux Difference: \n'  ~.(compare)~ 'minus'~.(base)))


p <- plot_ly(x = ~sqrt(1 - u^2) * cos(theta), y = ~sqrt(1 - u^2) * sin(theta), z = ~u) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Layout options in a 3d scatter plot",
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(title = bquote('Annual mean' ~CO[2] ~'Flux Difference: \n'  ~.(compare)~ 'minus'~.(base))),
      yaxis = list(title = "Sin"),
      zaxis = list(title = "Z")
    ))
p
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With HTML tags, for example:

```
yaxis = list(title = "Sin<sup>super</sup>")
```

More info [here](https://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/). Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: @Florian, how should I view this object? When I include a subscript in an axis label as you show above, the axis label disapears (when the plotly graph is viewed in both R Viewer and my web browser). Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to solve with such little information.Could you open a new question on SO with a reproducible example?